# Search for files using Google Drive SDK and the Text in File Comment meta-data

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

If I "insert" a new text file into Google Drive using the Google Drive SDK and I then "insert" a Comment (content:'abcxyz')  to that file, is there any way to search for files based on the text in the Comments.
I did a test using

```
File.List {q= fullText contains 'abcxyz'}
```

however it appears that comments are not included.